# What model should I use for multiple binary response variables?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, panel-data, multinomial-distribution

Consider many traders `j = 1, 2, ..., J` who can make the following trading decisions: a) buy, b) sell, c) do nothing since they have not previously bought, or d) do nothing since they do not want to sell, from a set of `I` stocks, where `i = 1, 2, ..., I`. I want to study the effect of market sentiment on these decisions.

I have a sentiment indicator for each stock on a daily basis `Sent_i,t` , and want to study its effect on the decision of traders in that stock. What is the correct model to use here?

If I had only 1 stock, I would run a multinomial regression where the response variable is the traders decision from the above mentioned set of 4 possible decisions and the independent variable is the sentiment score.

I am not sure how to extend this to multiple stocks.

Thank you for your advice.